# how to compute all the minors with a given order of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, determinants

I have a matrix m*n,
I want from it all the minors (the determinant of the submatrices) of order p.

I din't found anything good in the documentation, I could do it with a function written by my self, but I'd prefer something out of the box.

My real need is to check when,in a symbolic matrix, I have a fall of rank,and that happens when all the minors of that rank and above are zeros.

Any idea to do it with pure matlab comands? since there is a function to evalutate rank it has get the minors someway.

Comment: Can't you just use `rank`?

Comment: @LuisMendo, Hi Luis, the matrix rank gives the number of linearly independent rows (or columns) of a matrix while the (i-th,j-th) matrix minor is the determinate calculated from A's sub-matrix with the (i-th,j-th) row, column removed. Not sure how the rank would be related to the minor.

Comment: @roybatty Because the OP says "My real need is to check when,in a symbolic matrix, I have a fall of rank,and that happens when all the minors of that rank and above are zeros."

Comment: @LuisMendo, Ok good point Luis, I just figured that having the minors might still be useful to the OP, but otherwise, then yes, perhaps the rank is all that is needed.

Comment: my matrix is symbolic,rank gives me the number of indipendent rows(colums) if I evalutate the matrix. it doesn't give me the condition from wich I can check when my rank reduces,those are the minors==0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be some good answers already, but here is a simple explanation of what you can do:

Suppose you want to know the rank of every `i`-`j`th submatrix of a matrix `M`.

Now i believe the *simplest* way to get all ranks is to loop over all rows and columns and store this result in a matrix `R`.

```
M = magic(5);
R = NaN(size(M));
for i=1:size(M,1);
  for j=1:size(M,2);
    R(i,j) = rank(M([1:i-1 i+1:end],[1:j-1 j+1:end]));
  end
end
```

If you want all determinants replace `rank` with `det`.

Comment: that's clever, I love the way you get the submatrix...improving this one I'm sure I can solve it simpler than I tought

Answer (score 1):

This calculates the submatrix:

```
submatrix=@(M,r,c)M([1:r-1,r+1:end],[1:c-1,c+1:end])
```

You may either use 'arrayfun' and 'meshgrid' or two loops to iterate over all submatrices.

Comment: if the matrix is square I totally agree with you...will look into adapt this method for a rectangular one. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I don't have the Symbolic Toolbox but for a regular matlab array you can calculate the i-th, j-th minor with an anonymous function like this:

```
minor = @(i,j,A)det(A(setdiff([1:end],[i]),setdiff([1:end],[j])))
```

Or if you want the i-th, j-th cofactor, simply use:

```
cofactor = @(i,j,A)(-1)^(i+j)*det(A(setdiff([1:end],[i]),setdiff([1:end],[j])))
```

But as mentioned I don't know if something like this will work with the Symbolic Toolbox.  If it does not work as-is, perhaps this can at least give you some ideas on how you might implement the function for the symbolic case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes,thanks, that was pretty much what I had in mind to implement it...but of course it only works for n+n matrix in your case...with a bit of coding using your idea it can be done